# Bad Storage property exception when trying to implement linq-sql in a WCF service

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, datacontract

I've been trying to get a WCF service to access a file database that is stored on a local file system to no avail currently.

I created a database called data.mdf in visual studio 2010 and ran this sql query on it.

```
create table Person 
   (PersonID int identity (1000,1) not null, 
    Name nvarchar(50) not null,
    Address nvarchar(max)

create table ImportantPerson
   (ImportantPersonID int indentity(1000,1) not null, 
    Name nvarchar(50) not null,
    Address nvarchar(max)
```

and it successfully created the tables I wanted so I proceeded to create my DataContract:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
namespace MyDataContract
{
    public class DataDB: DataContext
    {
        public Table<Person> Persons;
        public Table<Important> Importants;
        public DataDB(string connstr)
            : base(connstr)
        {
        }

    }
 [DataContract]
    [Table(Name = "Person")]
public class Person
{
 private int _ID;
private String _Name;
private String _Address
public Person()
{
}
public Person(String Name, String Address)
{
_Name = Name;
_Address = Address;
}
[DataMember]
[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "PersonID", DbType="int not null", IsDbGenerated = true)]
public int PersonIdentification
{
get{ return _PersonID;}
set{ _PersonID = value;}
}
[DataMember]
[Column(Storage = "Name")]
{
get{ return _Name;}
set{ _Name = value;}
}
[DataMember]
[Column(Storage = "Address")]
{
get{ return _Address;}
set{_Address= value;}
}
public class Person
{
 private int _ID;
private String _Name;
private String _Address
public ImportantPerson()
{
}

public ImportantPerson(String Name, String Address)
{
_Name = Name;
_Address = Address;
}
[DataMember]
[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "ImportantPersonID", DbType="int not null", IsDbGenerated = true)]
public int PersonIdentification
{
get{ return _PersonID;}
set{ _PersonID = value;}
}
[DataMember]
[Column(Storage = "Name")]
{
get{ return _Name;}
set{ _Name = value;}
}
[DataMember]
[Column(Storage = "Address")]
{
get{ return _Address;}
set{_Address= value;}
}
```

When I try to instantiate a connection to the database

```
MyDataContract.DataDB data = new MyDataContract.DataDB(@"c:\data\data.mdf");
```

I get an exception

> Bad Storage property: 'PersonID' on
>   member
>   'MyDataContract.Person.PersonIdentification'.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong? From everything I've read this should work although I could miss something.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Sorry.  I did hit the code button but didn't realise i needed to highlight it first.

Answer (score 2):

The storage member must be private. You don't need the "Name=" tag if the public name is the same as the column name.

Answer (score 1):

Ladislav Mrnka is right but that was caused by a copy paste error.  I did solve it on my own, so in case someone has the same problem is will post how to fix it explicitly.
To fix it i had to also put the name of the field, and change the Storage attribute like so for : 
the table person has the "Name" and in the Person Object has the private instance variable "_Name" 
the property must be set up as:

```
[DataMember]
[Column(Name="Name",Storage="_Name")]
public String Name
{ 
get{...}
set{...}
}
```

Also should mention that I only successfully got it to work when the intance variable was private and the property was public.

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing ImportantPerson class in your code with Table attribute pointing to correct DB table and your code contains Person class twice.